# Finding documents containing a phrase in a big corpus

Tags: elasticsearch, match-phrase

I have a big corpus of text documents, which is dynamically updated. Every second nearly 100 new documents are added to this corpus.

I want to find the documents that contain an input phrase query (or one of the input phrases) in real-time. The queries also come sequentially with a high rate.

What is the right tool to implement this? Is Elasticsearch the appropriate one or there are lighter tools?

Comment: What database are you currently storing on?

Comment: @hamidbayat This is the intent of the question: to use Elasticsearch or something else.